# jQuery, html(), append() issue with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, append

i'm having problem writing data (html, contains tables) returned from an ajax request to a div.
The code works on Chrome, firefox..except IE (tested on IE 8)
I use the following code:

```
function ajax_test(option) {
    $('.loading').fadeIn();
    $('.roto_messages').empty();
    $.get("options.php?i="+option, function(data) {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $('.container').append(data);
        $('.container').fadeIn(1000);
        addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');
    });
}
```

I tried using .html() too but it did not work on IE aswell.
Thanks.

Comment: Well what is the html thats returned from the request? Also how exactly does it not work? IS the data not appended? Is it garbled or displaying incorrectly?

Comment: Did an empty response get cached by IE? Try appending a timestamp to the end of your request URL.

Comment: @prodigitalson the html contains tables, it has a lot of html codes, The data is grabbed through ajax. It get appended on firefox, chrome..except IE. (This issue is with jquery 1.4.2 only.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes I'd start with.  Cache your selectors when you create them initially and employ chaining.  That results in something like this:

```
function ajax_test(option) {
  var 
    $loading = $('.loading'),
    $container = $('.container');

  $loading.fadeIn();
  $('.roto_messages').empty();

  $.get("options.php", {i: option}, function(data) {
      $loading.hide();
      $container
        .append(data)
        .fadeIn(1000);

      addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');
  });
}
```

The next question is, what is `addthis`?  What does a utility like Firebug tell you when you run your ajax call?

Comment: Firebug doesn't complain about the code, everything works fine on other browsers except IE, i'll try that code tomorrow morning since i need to go sleep its very late.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a jQuery v1.4.2 bug, I tried the same code with jQuery 1.3.2 and it works fine in all browsers.
Btw, Using jQuery v1.4.2, I get the following error in IE:

```
Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 112
Char: 359
Code: 0
URI: http://www.mysite.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
```

Comment: In the table you are loading... are you making any other script calls from it that have property hashes like `{something: 1, something_else:2, etc: '...'}`?

Comment: From the tables it calls Addthis & Sharethis scripts but I already tried removing them, the problem is not coming from them.
But the problem is that it happens only with IE using jquery 1.4.2, jquery 1.3.2 works just fine!